# gameobject with on screen button, new input syste and same script affecting each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im making a tower defense game for mobile , and i made 2 gameObject for selecting a tower. the problem is, that when i added the 2nd gameobject with the samescript the script for selecting a tower and placing them is not right anymore. the tower that is for tower 1 is the prefab that is getting instantiated for the tower 2. but when its just 1 its working fine. im new in unity and dont know the best approach to making this. this is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using Cinemachine;

public class TowerPlacement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //References
    PlayerInput playerInput;
    private InputAction _touchPressedAction;
    private InputAction _touchPlacePressAction;
    private InputAction _touchPressAction;

    public GameObject[] _meleePlatform;
    CanvasEnabler canvasEnabler;
    //
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Canvas")]
    [SerializeField] GameObject _CharConfirmPlacementCanvas;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _charInfoCanvas;
    [SerializeField] string _platformTag;

    float placingGameTimeSpeed = 0.1f;
    float normalGameTimeSpeed = 1f;

    Ray _position;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Character Object")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _previewTower;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _tower;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Camera")]
    [SerializeField] private Camera _mainCam;

    [Header("Object Material")]
    [SerializeField] Material[] _materia;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Raycast")]
    [SerializeField] LayerMask _layerPlatform;
    float maxDistance;

    [SerializeField] CinemachineVirtualCamera vcam1;
    [SerializeField] CinemachineVirtualCamera vcam2;

    bool rayCastHit;

    Renderer rend;

    bool _isPlacing;

    // Material mat;

    private GameObject _instPreviewObj;
    private GameObject _instObj;

    public enum State
    {
        Default,
        Placing,
        HoldPlacing,
        Placed
    }

    private State currentState;


    private void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        _touchPressedAction = playerInput.actions["Pressed"];
        _touchPressAction = playerInput.actions["Press"];
        _touchPlacePressAction = playerInput.actions["PlacePress"];
        currentState = State.Default;

        _meleePlatform = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(_platformTag);

    }

    private void Update()
    {

        switch (currentState)
        {
            case State.Default:


                Time.timeScale = normalGameTimeSpeed;
                vcam1.Priority = 1;
                vcam2.Priority = 0;
                Debug.Log(currentState);
                _charInfoCanvas.SetActive(false);
                DisablePlatformCanvas();
                break;
            case State.Placing:
                Time.timeScale = placingGameTimeSpeed;
                EnablePlatformCanvas();
                //TODO:: Move the camera a bit when palcing
                vcam1.Priority = 0;
                vcam2.Priority = 1;
                Debug.Log(currentState);
                _charInfoCanvas.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case State.HoldPlacing:
                Debug.Log(currentState);
                _CharConfirmPlacementCanvas.SetActive(true);
                _CharConfirmPlacementCanvas.transform.position = _instPreviewObj.transform.position;

                break;
            case State.Placed:
                Debug.Log(currentState);

                break;
        }

    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _touchPressAction.performed += OnPressed;


    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _touchPressedAction.started -= OnPlacing;
        _touchPressedAction.canceled -= Hold;
        _touchPlacePressAction.canceled -= OnPressed;
    }

    public void OnPressed(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (_isPlacing)
        {
            _isPlacing = false;
            Destroy(_instPreviewObj);
            _CharConfirmPlacementCanvas.SetActive(false);
            currentState = State.Default;
            return;
        }
        if (currentState == State.Default)
        {
            Debug.Log("Press");
            _instPreviewObj = Instantiate(_previewTower, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);//previewModel
            _instPreviewObj.transform.parent = transform;
            //rend = _instPreviewObj.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            //rend.sharedMaterial = _materia[1];
            _isPlacing = true;
            currentState = State.Placing;
            _touchPressedAction.started += OnPlacing;
        }

    }

    public void ConfirmPlacement()
    {

        if (currentState == State.HoldPlacing)
        {
            DisablePlatformCanvas();
            _isPlacing = false;
            //rend.sharedMaterial = _materia[0];

            _instObj = Instantiate(_tower, _instPreviewObj.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(_instPreviewObj);
            _CharConfirmPlacementCanvas.SetActive(false);
            _touchPressedAction.canceled -= Hold;
            currentState = State.Default;
        }

    }

    public void OnCancelPlacement()
    {
        _touchPressedAction.started += OnPlacing;
        _CharConfirmPlacementCanvas.SetActive(false);
        _instPreviewObj.SetActive(false);
        currentState = State.Placing;
    }

    public void Hold(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (currentState == State.Placing)
        {
            _touchPressedAction.started -= OnPlacing;
            currentState = State.HoldPlacing;
        }
    }

    public void OnPlacing(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("Placing");
        if (_instPreviewObj != null)
        {
            _instPreviewObj.SetActive(true);
            _position = _mainCam.ScreenPointToRay(Touchscreen.current.position.ReadValue());
            rayCastHit = Physics.Raycast(_position, out RaycastHit raycastHit, maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, _layerPlatform);
            if (rayCastHit)
            {
                _instPreviewObj.transform.position = raycastHit.transform.position;
                Debug.DrawRay(_position.origin, _position.direction * 20, Color.red);
                Debug.Log("Touch Started");
                _touchPressedAction.canceled += Hold;
            }
        }

    }

    void EnablePlatformCanvas()
    {
        foreach (GameObject platform in _meleePlatform)
        {
            canvasEnabler = platform.GetComponent<CanvasEnabler>();
            canvasEnabler.EnableCanvas();
        }
    }

    void DisablePlatformCanvas()
    {
        foreach (GameObject platform in _meleePlatform)
        {
            canvasEnabler = platform.GetComponent<CanvasEnabler>();
            canvasEnabler.DisableCanvas();
        }
    }
}
```

i tried disabling only the script of the tower 2 and tower 1 works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all (though more a side-note) I personally would not constantly add and remove event callbacks - you might eventually end up with callbacks added twice or missing one where you expected one. For state control rather link everything up **once** and have and check state fields (bool / enum). That's way easier to keep an overview on, maintain and debug.

You even have such a field `currentState` which you could add checks on and ignore certain input events if you are not in the expected state instead of unsubscribe and subscribe again later.

---

Then further for both objects the check like

```
if (rayCastHit)
```

might be (in your case apparently **is**) `true` at the same time - but you actually rather want to check whether you even are interacting with **this** instance of the script! So e.g. like

```
if (rayCastHit && rayCastHit.gameObject == gameObject)
```

And then there is yet another similar flaw in

```
_meleePlatform = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(_platformTag);
```

which for both (all) instances of the tower will refer to the objects existing in the scene (at least in the moment their respective `Awake` was executed).

For those reasons I would usually rather not put this into the thing I want to interact with (you Tower) itself because then each and every instance will have redundant input events, perform a redundant raycast and check, etc.

I would rather move this into a central "Placement Controller" which handles hovering and interacting with all towers using a single raycast and single subscription to your input events.